# Jasmine `expect` never wrong in superagent `end`

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, supertest, superagent

My code doesn't do what it should. All the Jasmine `expect()` that are in a supertest `end()` callback function pass, even if they should not.

```
const app = require('../server')
const request = require('supertest')

describe('Client', function() {
  const agent = request.agent(app)

  it('connects to the server', function() {
    agent.post('/users/register/foobar').end(function(err, res) {
      done()
      expect(true).toBe(false) // Doesn't fail
    }
  })
})
```

Extract from `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
  "supertest": "^2.0.0"
}
```

The actual versions given by `npm list` are `jasmine@2.4.1` and `supertest@2.0.0`.

My guess is that `end()` never calls its function, but I just started yesterday with all that and I'm not sure what to do to solve the problem.

Do you see my error?

---

## Edit

As suggested, I switched lines to put the `done()` at the end, still no change, though.

Comment: why are you calling done before the expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're wrong to use the function "done".
Try:

```
it('connects to the server', function(done) {
agent.post('/users/register/foobar').end(function(err, res) {
  expect(true).toBe(false); // Doesn't fail
  done();
}  })
```

For more details, check the jasmine documentation: [Jasmine documentation: Asynchronous Support](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't declare the `done` parameter. You helped!